# The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building OutputPage(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus]): Unexpected null value

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have done the following codes and no dart files are showing error but an error is thrown when I process it. The error is Unexpected null value

The Codes are as follows :

> main.dart

```
import 'package:bmi_calculator/output_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';
import 'output_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());
 
class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff111428),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff111428),
        shadowColor: Color(0xFFEEF1F9),
                  ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => InputPage(),
        '/first': (context) => OutputPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> input_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'container_cards.dart';
import 'first_line_containers.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/container_cards.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/constants.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/calculator_brain.dart';

 
enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}
 
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}
 
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender? selectedGender;
  int heightStartValue = 180;
  int weightStartValue = 60;
  int ageStartValue = 21;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'BMI CALCULATOR',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ContainerCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    myColor: selectedGender == Gender.male
                        ? kActiveBoxColors
                        : kInactiveBoxColors,
                    myCardDetails: FirstLineContainers(
                      myStrings: "MALE",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ContainerCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    myColor: selectedGender == Gender.female
                        ? kActiveBoxColors
                        : kInactiveBoxColors,
                    myCardDetails: FirstLineContainers(
                      myIcons: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.female),
                      myStrings: "FEMALE",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ContainerCard(
              myColor: kInactiveBoxColors,
              myCardDetails: FittedBox(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'HEIGHT',
                      style: kTextStyles,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          heightStartValue.toString(),
                          style: kNumberStyles,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 3),
                        Text(
                          'Cms',
                          style: kTextStyles,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        activeTrackColor: kActiveTrackColor,
                        inactiveTrackColor: kInactiveTrackColor,
                        thumbColor: kThumbColor,
                        overlayColor: kOverlayColor,
                        thumbShape: kThumbShape,
                        overlayShape: kOverlayShape,
                        valueIndicatorShape: kValueIndicatorShape,
                        valueIndicatorColor: kValueIndicatorColor,
                      ),
                      child: Slider(
                        value: heightStartValue.toDouble(),
                        min: 80,
                        max: 240,
                        divisions: 160,
                        label: "$heightStartValue",
                        onChanged: (double changedValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            heightStartValue = changedValue.round();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ContainerCard(
                    myColor: kInactiveBoxColors,
                    myCardDetails: FittedBox(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('WEIGHT', style: kTextStyles),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                            textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                weightStartValue.toString(),
                                style: kNumberStyles,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 3),
                              Text(
                                'KGs',
                                style: kTextColor,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              CustomButton(
                                iconMarker: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                afterPress: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    weightStartValue--;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 20,
                              ),
                              CustomButton(
                                iconMarker: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                afterPress: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    weightStartValue++;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ContainerCard(
                    myColor: kInactiveBoxColors,
                    myCardDetails: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'AGE',
                          style: kTextStyles,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              ageStartValue.toString(),
                              style: kNumberStyles,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 3),
                            Text(
                              'Yrs',
                              style: kTextColor,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            CustomButton(
                                afterPress: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ageStartValue--;
                                  });
                                },
                                iconMarker: FontAwesomeIcons.minus),
                            SizedBox.fromSize(
                              size: Size(20, 0),
                            ),
                            CustomButton(
                                afterPress: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ageStartValue++;
                                  });
                                },
                                iconMarker: FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          BottomButtons(
            buttonText: 'Calculate Your BMI',
            onTap: () {
              CalculatorBrain calc = CalculatorBrain(
                  weight: weightStartValue, height: heightStartValue);
              Navigator.pushNamed(
                context,
                '/first',
                arguments: calc,
                // arguments: OutputPage(
                //   getOutput: calc.outputBMI(),
                //   getNumber: calc.calculateBMI(),
                //   getInterpretation: calc.interpretationBMI(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
 
class BottomButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  BottomButtons({this.buttonText, this.onTap});
 
  final String? buttonText;
  final Function? onTap;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        onTap!();
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 21),
        child: Text(
          buttonText!,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            letterSpacing: 2,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: kBottomBarHeight,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          color: kBottomContainerColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
 
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({@required this.iconMarker, this.afterPress});
 
  final IconData? iconMarker;
  final Function? afterPress;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Icon(iconMarker),
      onPressed: () {
        afterPress!();
      },
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
      highlightColor: Color(0x294C4F5E),
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 56, height: 56),
    );
  }
}
```

> output_page.dart

```
import 'package:bmi_calculator/container_cards.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/input_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/calculator_brain.dart';

class OutputPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CalculatorBrain calc =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as CalculatorBrain;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'BMI CALCULATOR',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Your Parameters',
              style: kOutputText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: ContainerCard(
                myColor: kInactiveBoxColors,
                myCardDetails: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      calc.calculateBMI(),
                      style: kNumberStyles,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      calc.resultBMI().toUpperCase(),
                      style: kResultText,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Normal BMI Range : \n 18.5 - 25 kg/m2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFFF9E1B1),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      calc.analysisBMI(),
                      style: kAnalysisTextStyles,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BottomButtons(
              buttonText: 'Re-Calculate',
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> calculator_brain.dart

import 'dart:math';

```
class CalculatorBrain {
  final int weight;
  final int height;
 
  CalculatorBrain({
    required this.weight,
    required this.height,
  });
 
  double? _bmi;
 
  String calculateBMI() {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
 
  String outputBMI() {
    if (_bmi <= 16.0) {
      return 'Underweight(Severe thinness)';
    } else if (_bmi < 16.9) {
      return 'Underweight(Moderate thinness)';
    } else if (_bmi < 18.4) {
      return 'Underweight(Mild thinness)';
    } else if (_bmi <= 25) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else if (_bmi < 29.9) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi < 34.9) {
      return 'Obese(Class I)';
    } else if (_bmi < 39.9) {
      return 'Obese(Class II)';
    } else
      return '(Obese(Class III)';
  }
 
  String analysisBMI() {
    if (_bmi <= 16.0) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Possible nutritional deficiency and osteoporosis. This is severe. Please consult your Physician Immediately';
    } else if (_bmi < 16.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Possible nutritional deficiency and osteoporosis. Please consult your Physician Immediately';
    } else if (_bmi < 18.4) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Possible nutritional deficiency and osteoporosis. Your Physician should be consulted';
    } else if (_bmi <= 25) {
      return 'Congratulations! \n You are living a healthy life. Please keep it up';
    } else if (_bmi < 29.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Moderate risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Please take care';
    } else if (_bmi < 34.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n High risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Metabolic Syndrome';
    } else if (_bmi < 39.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Very High risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Metabolic Syndrome. Please consult your Physician';
    } else
      return 'Health Risk : \n Extremely High risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Metabolic Syndrome. Physician consultation advised immediately';
  }
}
```

> container_cards.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class ContainerCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ContainerCard({this.myColor, this.myCardDetails, this.onPress});
 
  final Color? myColor;
  final Widget? myCardDetails;
  final Function? onPress;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => {onPress?.call()},
      child: Container(
        child: myCardDetails,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: myColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(12),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> first_line_containers.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/constants.dart';
 
class FirstLineContainers extends StatelessWidget {
  FirstLineContainers(
      {this.myIcons = const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.male), this.myStrings});
 
  final Icon myIcons;
  final String? myStrings;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          myIcons.icon,
          size: 60.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 15),
        Text(myStrings!, style: kTextStyles),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> constants.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     
    const kBottomBarHeight = 80.0;
    const kBottomContainerColor = Color(0xFF363A3D);
     
    const kInactiveBoxColors = Color(0xFF1D1F33);
    const kActiveBoxColors = Color(0xFF575861);
     
    const kTextStyles = TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xFF8D8D98),
      fontSize: 22,
    );
     
    const kTextColor = TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xFF8D8D98),
    );
     
    const kNumberStyles = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
      fontSize: 50,
    );
     
    const kActiveTrackColor = Color(0xFFE4706F);
    const kInactiveTrackColor = Color(0xFF8D602A);
    const kThumbColor = Color(0xFFEBAB25);
    const kOverlayColor = Color(0x29EBAB25);
    const kThumbShape = RoundSliderThumbShape(
      enabledThumbRadius: 12,
    );
    const kOverlayShape = RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 25);
    const kValueIndicatorShape = PaddleSliderValueIndicatorShape();
    const kValueIndicatorColor = Color(0xFFEBAB25);
     
    const kOutputText = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      fontSize: 30,
      color: Color(0xFF8E919E),
    );
    
    const kResultText = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      fontSize: 30,
      letterSpacing: 3,
      color: Color(0xFFF4C18B),
    );

const kAnalysisTextStyles = TextStyle(
  color: Color(0xFF8D8D98),
  fontSize: 16,
);
```

The following errors are thrown:

Exception caught by widgets library

```
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building OutputPage(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus]):

Unexpected null value.



The relevant error-causing widget was:

  OutputPage file:///C:/Users/Debasis/StudioProjects/bmi_calculator/lib/main.dart:33:32

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49      throw_

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 518:63  nullCheck

packages/bmi_calculator/calculator_brain.dart 20:15                                                                            outputBMI

packages/bmi_calculator/output_page.dart 51:27                                                                                 build

packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4648:28                                                                            build
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: Your OutputPage is missing, and this is where the error is occurring.

Comment: I'm so sorry I missed out on that. I edited it and also found a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

**The solution to my Problem :**

In the *calculator_brain.dart* I needed to put in **double _bmi = 0;** instead of *double? _bmi;*

> calculator_brain.dart

```
import 'dart:math';

class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({
    required this.weight,
    required this.height,
  });

  final int weight;
  final int height;

  double _bmi = 0;

  String calculateBMI() {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }

  String resultBMI() {
    
    if (_bmi <= 16.0) {
      return 'Underweight\n(Severe thinness)';
    } else if (_bmi < 16.9) {
      return 'Underweight\n(Moderate thinness)';
    } else if (_bmi < 18.4) {
      return 'Underweight\n(Mild thinness)';
    } else if (_bmi <= 25) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else if (_bmi < 29.9) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi < 34.9) {
      return 'Obese\n(Class I)';
    } else if (_bmi < 39.9) {
      return 'Obese\n(Class II)';
    } else
      return '(Obese\n(Class III)';
  }

  String analysisBMI() {
    if (_bmi <= 16.0) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Possible nutritional deficiency and osteoporosis. This is severe. Please consult your Physician Immediately';
    } else if (_bmi < 16.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Possible nutritional deficiency and osteoporosis. Please consult your Physician Immediately';
    } else if (_bmi < 18.4) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Possible nutritional deficiency and osteoporosis. Your Physician should be consulted';
    } else if (_bmi <= 25) {
      return 'Congratulations! \n You are living a healthy life. Please keep it up';
    } else if (_bmi < 29.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Moderate risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Please take care';
    } else if (_bmi < 34.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n High risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Metabolic Syndrome';
    } else if (_bmi < 39.9) {
      return 'Health Risk : \n Very High risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Metabolic Syndrome. Please consult your Physician';
    } else
      return 'Health Risk : \n Extremely High risk of developing heart disease, high blood pressure, stroke, diabetes mellitus. Metabolic Syndrome. Physician consultation advised immediately';
  }
}
```

Comment: It is really weird that we get such a horrible error for just a question mark! and initialization!